# Keil uVision5 problems

Tags: c++, debugging, embedded, printf, keil

I have never used `keil` before this project that I am working on, but I have always been able to just say printf("hello); and it work.
However with `keil`, I am not getting this to show in the debug (`printf`) viewer.
I have sprinkled statements like this throughout my main function but nothing prints.
Do I need to do something to get this to work?

Comment: I assume you are referring to Keil ARM-MDK?  What processor are you using?  It needs to have the ARM ITM module to do what you want.

Comment: I´m using the ARM cortex M4 @Clifford

Comment: Then my answer applies.  Keil produce toolchains for other targets where that answer might not have applied. You should generally quote the exact product rather than a company name, including version number.  You should also "improve" the question by editing it rather than responding via comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [retarget the library](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_retargetarm7.htm) to match your hardware and/or development environment.  Typically a minimal retarget will map stdio to a UART - though you could implement a full file system.

If you want stdout data to appear in the *Debug(printf)* window, you have implement the retarget to write to the ITM stimulus port as described [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulinkpro/ulinkpro_trace_itm_viewer.htm).  Any data output to stdout will then appear in the debug windows - not just `printf`.

The library is retargettable because you may use stdio for your application needs rather than just debug.  The advantage of using a UART for stdio rather than ITM is that it is bidirectional, and will work without a debugger attached, so you might want to consider that in any case.

Comment: the ITM stimulus port code gives me errors on the __stdout

Comment: @user3729617 : That is a different question, and without knowing what the errors (or rather the diagnostics) are, I cannot really comment.